# Horizontal Number Picker in android

Tags: android, layout, numbers, picker

I want a horizontal NUMBER picker, I don't want any code but any library or suggestion is welcome.
I have searched but didn't get satisfactory [answer](http://goo.gl/1E5KzA) it may be for IOS.

The picker I want is like this:

[image: Horizontal Number Picker]

Comment: i have google so i got from that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this, it seems to come close to what you're looking for :

https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel